# CoSign Cloud - Possible to sign binary file or buffer? (Detached Signature)

Tags: digital-signature, cosign-api

The CoSign documentation indicates that is possible to sign an arbitrary binary buffer and create a detached signature. See http://developer.arx.com/examples/sapi_local_detached_signatures/

However, looking at the WebAgent and SOAP API docs this does not seem to be correct.

Question: Is this only supported for the local API?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Larry's answer, note that you can easily sign buffers using the [CoSign Signature API](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.2/Default.htm#doc_7.2/Sign%20Buffer.htm).
Also, [here](http://developer.arx.com/quick-start/cosign-api-endpoints/) you can the API endpoint for CoSign Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The web agent api signs pdf, word, and excel docs.

The CoSign Signature, Local, and Soap APIs can be used to sign data buffers. They can be used with the CoSign cloud service or with a CoSign appliance.

Please note that the cloud service may not be used for batch signing.